# Xamarin Unable to find a constructor to use for type xxx.xxx.xxx

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xamarin.forms

I'm searching all over the internet to find a solution for my problem, yet I can't find one that worked.

So I'm trying to `parse` some `Json` data to an app, `async` with an `url`.

Now, this here is the code I'm using to call the API:

```
namespace RadioApp.Model
{
    public static class APIManager
    {
        public const string baseUrl = "https://www.sunnieday.nl/api/radio/stats/info";

        // This adds base url.
        public static string GenerateUrl(string urlString)
        {
            return string.Format(baseUrl + urlString);
        }

        // Metod 1: Downloading all the base data from current DJ
        public static async Task<APIResponse> GetListenPageData()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "Application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36");

            //Methode GetStringAsync gaat via een url de nodige data ophalen.
            string result = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);
            Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + result);

            // De Json string naar objecten van onze klasses
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(result);
            Debug.WriteLine("data: " + data);

            return data;
        }
    }
```

This returns the data like so:

```
[0:] Result: {"data":{"listeners":26,"song":"Ed Sheeran - Bibia Be Ye Ye","live_dj":"Auto DJ","mini_rooster":[],"song_history":[{"playedat":1509537573,"title":"Ed Sheeran - Bibia Be Ye Ye","metadata":{"tit2":"Ed Sheeran - Bibia Be Ye Ye"}},{"playedat":1509537292,"title":"Katy Perry - Swish Swish","metadata":{"tit2":"Katy Perry - Swish Swish"}},{"playedat":1509536950,"title":"Fall Out Boy - Champion","metadata":{"tit2":"Fall Out Boy - Champion"}},{"playedat":1509536744,"title":"J Balvin - Mi Gente (Original Mix)","metadata":{"tit2":"J Balvin - Mi Gente (Original Mix)"}},{"playedat":1509536364,"title":"Axwell and Ingrosso - On My Way","metadata":{"tit2":"Axwell and Ingrosso - On My Way"}},{"playedat":1509536095,"title":"Green Day - Boulevard Of Broken Dreams","metadata":{"tit2":"Green Day - Boulevard Of Broken Dreams"}},{"playedat":1509535745,"title":"Bingo Players - Knock You Out","metadata":{"tit2":"Bingo Players - Knock You Out"}},{"playedat":1509535520,"title":"Rockwell - Somebody's Watching Me","metadata":{"tit2":"Rockwell - Somebody's Watching Me"}},{"playedat":1509535118,"title":"DJ Snake ft. Lauv - A Different Way","metadata":{"tit2":"DJ Snake ft. Lauv - A Different Way"}},{"playedat":1509534885,"title":"Miley Cyrus - Malibu","metadata":{"tit2":"Miley Cyrus - Malibu"}}]}}
```

Now, I'm trying to make objects out of it (I don't know how I could use them else), but here it doesn't work at all...

I used the "paste special as Json Classes" command in VisualStudio and then I get this:

```
namespace RadioApp.Model
{
    public class APIResponse
    {

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Data data { get; set; }
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public int listeners { get; set; }
            public string song { get; set; }
            public string live_dj { get; set; }
            public object[] mini_rooster { get; set; }
            public Song_History[] song_history { get; set; }
        }

        public class Song_History
        {
            public int playedat { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
        }

        public class Metadata
        {
            public string tit2 { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Now, when I try to access the code in the `ListenPage.xaml.cs` I made (and use as base page), it doesn't load the data and returns a huge error;

```
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
[0:] Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type RadioApp.Model.Data. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'data', line 1, position 8.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract objectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id, System.Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator) [0x000d5] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0013f] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0006d] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00053] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <91135d4732444fbda60dae87939ac9ab>:0 
  at RadioApp.Model.APIManager+<GetListenPageData>d__2.MoveNext () [0x000eb] in C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Sunnieday\SunniedayRadio\RadioApp\RadioApp\RadioApp\Model\APIManager.cs:34
```

Now here you see the method I'm calling to get the data:

```
public partial class ListenPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListenPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowLisenPageData();
        }

        private async Task ShowLisenPageData()
        {
            try
            {
                APIResponse data = await APIManager.GetListenPageData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

What have I already tried?

I already tried to "add a base constructor" by adding `public Data() {}` etc... to all classes, didn't work.
I tried to do this solution:

> In the 'Android options' tab of the project properties, there is a
>   'linker' tab. Is the selected option in the 'Linking' dropdown "Sdk
>   Assemblies only" or is it "Sdk and user assemblies"?
>
> If it is the latter, the parameterless constructor is skipped when
>   linking, because no use is detected. So change it to "Sdk Assemblies
>   only".

Didn't work either, so I'm out of options now, could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What if you annotate all your classes (`Data` etc) with `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` attribute?

Comment: That doesn't help either, same error.

Comment: I see error refers to type `RadioApp.Model.Data` but type you have is `RadioApp.Model.APIResponse.Data` (child class of APIResponse). Maybe you have 2 `Data` types?

Comment: Well, I don't know where it links to `RadioApp.Model.Data`, since I never use that, I always reffer to `RadioApp.Model.APIResponse.Data`, I can't see what's causing the issue here...

Comment: @Evk I can post the code on GitHub so you can pull the whole project?

Comment: Well won't hurt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157996/discussion-between-robin-and-evk).